# How to get a value from html to flash (other than flashvars)

Tags: html, actionscript-3

I need to retrieve a value in as3 from a html page on a particular event say "mouse-click". We cannot use flashVars as it is obvious that i need the value on a particular event.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). I don't have time to explain further but there is a lot of documentation about this. It is very easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<param>` tag, and edit them with javascript (jQuery) on events. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_param.asp (perhaps not the best example).